# Removing docker Image tag id from image names

Tags: docker, automation, notepad++

I have list of docker image names like below

```
aa-bb-cc-2.10.0-14
aa-bc-cd-ef-ghi-2.10.0-410
```

I want this to be replaced as

```
aa-bb-cc:2.10.0-14
aa-bc-cd-ef-ghi:2.10.0-410
```

There are a lot of such docker images names where I want to remove the docker image tag from the complete name. How can I replace all at a single go. Any script or formatting in Notepad++. Can anyone help with this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?<=[a-z])-(?=\d)`
- Replace with: `:`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?<=[a-z])      # positive lookbehind, make sure we have a letter before
-               # hyphen
(?=\d)          # positive lookahead, make sure we have a digit after
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. It solved my problem. Can you please help which document you follow to get these quick help or learn such

Comment: @SandeepKumar: You're welcome, glad it helps. [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/) is a site to learn regex, and [here](https://regex101.com/) a site to test your regex.